# Minipage footnote is inside tikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, minipage

I have a minipage, and inside of it I have a footnote and a tikZ picture. Now my problem is, that the footnote text goes inside the last node of my tikZ picture. That is not what I want – and it's very weird actually.

### Code and output

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{a footnote}% I cannot use \footnotemark etc
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]% I need these two options
        \draw[ultra thick, black] (0,0) -- node[sloped,below,text width=12cm,text centered]
{\lipsum[4]} (11,-3);% the text has to have a maximal width
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

### First workaround

When I remove the `text width = 12cm` completely, the footnote moves back under the end of the text:

[image: Screenshot after workaround]

But I need the text to have a maximal width. So this is not very satisfying. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry that the sample outputs do not match the MWE — will change the pictures soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

where we learn tikz uses minipage internally:-)

this saves and restores the footnotes to stop tikz seeing it, so the footnote comes in the right place, the rotated tikz picture overprints but I guess someone who knows tikz can fix that...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{a footnote}% I cannot use \footnotemark etc
    \setbox0\box\csname@mpfootins\endcsname
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]% I need these two options
        \draw[ultra thick, black] (0,0) -- node[sloped,below,text width=12cm,text centered]
{\lipsum[4]} (11,-3);% the text has to have a maximal width
    \end{tikzpicture}\global\setbox\csname@mpfootins\endcsname\box0
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ normally uses an `hbox` to store the node content but when a line breaking is needed, it switches to a minipage to allow for `text width` or `align=center` etc such that the line breaks are respected and/or inserted. That's why removing `text width` works.

Comment: @percusse clearly yes although it probably ought just use `\vbox{{\@parboxrerstore` so an internal version of `minipage` that doesn't hijack footnotes. (although you could say that latex could handle nested minipages better:-)

Comment: Thank you, very nice! I use the code inside a custom package, so I had to change `\csname@mpfootins\endcsname` to `\@mpfootins`. But I really like the `\csname`-method, I think it is much nicer than a `\makeatletter` `:)`

Comment: @ralfix I should probably have used `\csname @mpfootins\endcsname` then it would have worked in both contexts

Answer (score 3):

This is why LaTeX is beautiful... Another solution :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\savenotes
\lipsum[1]\footnote{a footnote}% I cannot use \footnotemark etc
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]% I need these two options
        \draw[ultra thick, black] (0,0) -- node[sloped,below,text width=12cm,text centered]
{\lipsum[4]} (11,-3);% the text has to have a maximal width
    \end{tikzpicture}
\spewnotes
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution (which is not a real solution) is to do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{a footnote}% I cannot use \footnotemark etc
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]% I need these two options
        \draw[ultra thick, black] (0,0) -- node[sloped,below]
{
    \begin{tabu}to 12cm {X[c]}
    \lipsum[4]
    \end{tabu}
} (11,-3);% the text has to have a maximal width
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice (and a real!) solution, but I needed the text to be centered, not justified – I sometimes have only a few words "under the line", these get left-aligned in your solution. But you couldn't know, it wasn't clear from the MWE.

Comment: In that case I think you can use the `tabu` package with X[c] identifier.

Comment: @ralfix just add `\centering` or (much more efficiently) instead of tabularx use `\parbox{12cm}{\centering....}`

Comment: I edited my answer to work with `tabu` and get the text centered. However, I think the previous comment by @DavidCarlisle probably is the best approach.

Comment: @cacamailg the `tabu`-solution does not hyphenate words – is there another identifier which does that?
@DavidCarlisle another answere? `:)`

Comment: @ralfix It is not tabu stopping the hyphenation it is centering If you ask for (the default latex) centering then lines can be short so hyphenation will only be used for words that are longer than a line. Perhaps you want `ragged2e` package and `\Centering` instead which limits how short the lines can get (so tex will hyphenate if necessary)

Comment: @ralfix I am not sure about the hyphenation in `tabu`. I meant the solution `\parbox{12cm}{\centering....}`