# How to add a footnote in a text inside tikzpicture in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, footnotes

How can I add a footnote to a text that is inside a tikzpicture in latex?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Welcome! The answer to your question could depend on a lot of things: it is this a standalone picture, it is integrated into a document, which type of document class you use, if you use `hyperref`... could you please post a simple [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can help you?

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107603/create-a-footnote-in-node-in-a-tikzpicture

Answer (score 7):

You can do footnotes in TikZ pictures the same way you do footnotes in tables or figures, i.e. either you use `\footnotemark` inside and `\footnotetext` outside or you wrap the text in a `minipage` to have the footnote placed directly underneath in the middle of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\textheight}{3cm} % only for demo!
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={
    draw=red, rectangle, rounded corners
  }]
  \node (a) {Hello world!\footnotemark};

  \node [below of=a] (b) {%
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
      foobar\footnote{This footnote is inside the picture}
    \end{minipage}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\footnotetext{This footnote is outside the picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]